# Batch - Executing multiple ping .bat with .txt export

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ping

```
@echo off 

:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
echo Requesting administrative privileges...
goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /B

:gotAdmin
if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
pushd "%CD%"
CD /D "%~dp0"
:--------------------------------------
```

Above is a tidy snippet of code I found which prompts the user to elevate the executed .bat to admin level... when I combine it with a simple cmd command, say: "ipconfig > c:\ipconfig.txt", it works a treat, however, when I combine it with this more adventurous cmd command:

```
FOR /L %i IN (1,1,4) DO ping -a -n 1 192.168.1.%i | FIND /i "Reply" >> c:\pings.txt
notepad.exe c:\pings.txt
```

I get no exported .txt whatsoever... what I hope to achieve is a .bat file that pings a select range of IP's and prints the result in a text file... I've tried strategically including quotations marks, here, there and everywhere but to no avail... any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: It is not necessary to edit the title *just* to add a "Batch -" prefix - this information is already conveyed in the tags (and also in the title itself as ".bat").

Comment: my apologies, was meant for personal file keeping : /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use double percent signs for `for loop` variables in shell scripts:

```
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,4) DO ping -a -n 1 192.168.1.%%i | FIND /i "Reply"
```